# Preventing spam registration /url redirect

Tags: 7, users, advertising

im getting more and more spam account registrations. what is the simplest way to handle this if one does not need browser based registration? people register the REST/services way via an app.

can this be achieved without additional modules? e.g. server redirect?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need user self-registration then just disable that functionality.

To do this go to :
/admin/config/people/accounts (Admin > Configuration > People > Account Settings)

And for the **Who can register accounts?** setting choose **Administrators only**.

If later on you decide that you need that functionality, you can enable it back and then just add a captcha to your user registration form, or integrate something like [honeypot](https://www.drupal.org/project/honeypot) or [logintoboggan](https://www.drupal.org/project/logintoboggan).

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. people can register themselves  - they download the app and register through the app.

Comment: So does your app rely on the drupal registration mechanism ? Or can you just disable the functionality in drupal an let your app handle things ?

Comment: yes, im relying on the drupal registration. im using this masterpiece https://github.com/jbeuckm/drupal-client

Comment: The REST mechanism allows for handing extra fields in the user registration form. (see http://www.thirdandgrove.com/creating-users-in-drupal-with-the-services-modules-rest-api/ at the end of article). See if you can add a captcha. Alternatively, a a rough solution a simple hidden field with an arbitrary value could help you differenciate drupal-client registrations and web interface registrations.

Comment: thx for the suggestions - i can already differentiate with the help of a custom field. in combination with rules its kinda working and im blocking spam accounts. however, they are set up in the first place. would a server-side redirect from the login url somehow work or would it prevent rest registration as well?

Comment: I can't say without a close look at how things are set up. Do try and see how it goes. Also see if logintoboggan can be of any help to you.

Comment: will do. your suggestions and the link in particular is definitely appreciated. thanks